# Can I use Revolution Slider in React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, revolution-slider

So I can produce in React the same html which is generated here in the Hero: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/zircona-it-solutions-technology-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/26902789

but to get the animation, need to have a javascript, yes?

Where can I get that javascript?

Or is this a css, I think not. What is the way to reproduce this kind of animation?

Or is it any more advanced, free easy solution to do similar animations?

[image]

---

Loking at this jQuery solution:

http://zulijani.com/slider-revolution/sources/01.Sample-Boxed.html

```
<li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1000" >
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="images/darkblurbg.jpg"  alt="darkblurbg"  data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYERS -->
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption lightgrey_divider skewfromrightshort fadeout"
                        data-x="85"
                        data-y="224"
                        data-speed="500"
                        data-start="1200"
                        data-easing="Power4.easeOut">My Caption
                    </div>
```

The thing I do not get, why here plain `div`s are used but in the linked template custom html elements are used.

Comment: That is JavaScript animation but can also be done through CSS in some hacky ways. If you want to check one of the JS animation libraries, here it is: https://greensock.com/gsap/

Comment: Ahh yes, but is it easy to convert the animations are already part of the template, I guess not. It should be possible to run Revolution Slider animation with React aslo, don't you think?

Comment: I was searching about using Slider Revolution and React. Got your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72762815/how-to-use-rs-module-wrap-in-a-react-application It was almost a year back. Haha! There is a jQuery version for Slider Revolution, you can try that including that. Sadly there is no React version maintained by them yet I guess.

Comment: Loking at this jQuery solution:

http://zulijani.com/slider-revolution/sources/01.Sample-Boxed.html The thing I do not get, why here plain divs are used but in the linked template custom html elements are used.

Comment: I assume since jQuery has been long existing, they used the regular elements when custom elements were not possible and then continue with the development with that as the base. I see that in the WordPress plugin, it is wrapped in ReactJS blocks which are newer and of course when custom elements were possible so they continue with that. Both options are fine.